# Cannot find my Pokemon account

Tags: pokemon-go

After downloading the update, it logged me out and now does not recognize my email. Even after trying to get my password reset, it said that my email isn't with a Pokemon account. I've used this account for a few weeks already and now it says I have no account. This is the only email I use.

Comment: Have you ever used a GPS spoofer, shared the account with others, used it on a jailbroken/rooted phone, or done any other sort of "cheaty" actions? If so, your account may have been banned.

Comment: No. I've just used it as normal. No cheating.

Comment: Have you looked under your couch? Maybe it fell. (Or more seriously, did you look at one of the million questions on the homepage with similar problems)

Comment: I've even tried contacting support but nothing.

Comment: When I tried to reset my account, it said that my email doesn't have an account with it. I've logged in with it before after logging out.